# Quelle est la prononciation standard du « h » aspiré ?

Tags: usage, prononciation, h-aspiré

Les mots commençant par un *h* aspiré peuvent être prononcés de plusieurs manières différentes en français :

- Sans prononcer le *h* : *les halles* -> `[leal]`
- Avec coup de glotte : *les halles* -> `[leʔal]`
- Avec *h* : les halles -> `[lehal]`

entre autres.

Y en a-t-il une considérée comme standard ? Une plus courante ? Y a-t-il des différences suivant les variétés de français ?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_aspir%C3%A9) n'est pas d'une utilité flagrante.

Comment: Pour le *h* prononcé avec plus qu'un coup de glotte, j'aimerais une référence, parce que je n'ai jamais entendu ça (sauf professeur bienveillant qui fait une dictée).

Comment: @Gilles je n'ai pas de référence écrite, mais je l'ai entendu prononcé par quelques personnes âgées du Berry et de Bourgogne.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En note du tableau des consonnes du français (tableau qui ne comporte ni `[h]` ni `[ʔ]`), on trouve chez Grevisse :

> **Remarque** -- On ne trouve pas dans ce tableau de son qui corresponde à la lettre *h*. […] Il n'y a un son réel que dans des emplois excessif [p.e. *hop !* ou encore en insistant sur des mots comme *hideux* ou même des mots qui ne commencent pas par un *h* aspiré, *hénaurme* (pour *énorme*) a par exemple été utilisé dans sa correspondance par Flaubert pour rendre cet effet].
>
> Le français de certaines régions connaît encore l'*h* aspiré comme phonème.

Comment: Dans l'exemple cité par la question, il y a souvent un coup de glotte n'en déplaise aux lecteurs du tableau de Grévisse. Dans des exemples où une consonne enchainable précède le h dit aspiré, un coup de glotte apparaît : *par haine* contraste systématiquement avec *parraine*.

Answer (score 7):

Les sons [h] et [ʔ] n'existent pas en français. La seule prononciation correcte (au moins dans le dialecte « standard » de France) est la première. En fait, le « h » aspiré ou non ne se prononce jamais, il ne fait que modifier les règles de sandhi (élision, liaison).

Comment: Tu as des sources?

Comment: Il y a un chapitre sur le français dans le *Handbook of the International Phonetic Association*, par exemple. Mais n'importe quelle grammaire contenant un inventaire des phonèmes du français, http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_français par exemple, montrera l'absence du coup de glotte et de la fricative glottale sourde.

Comment: On pourrait ajouter par plaisanterie que l'enregistrement d'à peu près n'importe quel francophone parlant anglais ou allemand est une preuve de l'absence du [h] en français :-)

Comment: Je pense qu'à de très rares exceptions près (qu'il serait intéressant de trouver), tout francophone apprend dés les premières années que le 'h' ne se prononce jamais et est ignoré complètement (hors règles d'élision/liaison).

Comment: @JPP Des phonèmes, oui, mais pas des sons. Le `[h]` est très rare mais le coup de glotte est assez courant.

Comment: @Evpok: je suis d'accord que j'ai été négligent dans mon commentaire : le mieux serait de consulter ce que dit un bouquin de phonétique parlant du français, comme le IPA Handbook. En revanche, je ne trouve pas le coup de glotte très fréquent en français. En fait, à part dans quelques onomatopées, ou vraiment pour faire remarquer à quelqu'un qu'il vient de faire une liaison fautive (« on dit [le.'ʔa.ʁi.ko] ! »), je ne vois pas vraiment de cas où on l'utilise réellement.

Comment: @JPP On l'emploie beaucoup pour accentuer un mot qui commence par une voyelle « Il est *où* ? » -> `[ilɛ'ʔu]`, « fromage *et* dessert ? » -> `[fʁɔmaʒ. 'ʔe desɛʁ]`. En ce qui concerne son emploi pour le *h* aspiré, je sais que je le fais parfois pour *les halles* et *la honte*, par exemple.

Comment: Effectivement : ce qui explique mon exemple, d'ailleurs : comme j'ai essayé de le rendre dans ma transcription, si on insiste sur l'absence de liaison, on va naturellement accentuer la première syllabe du mot. Écoute, je vais essayer de trouver ce soir une source qui fait plus autorité, mais je suis catégorique : je prononce <les halles> [leal].

Comment: Damnéd! Certaines autorités (et quelles autorités !) sont [de ton côté.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3gVto7j3LI)

Comment: Le coup de glotte est très commun en français, on en trouve par exemple pour le h aspiré dans *par amour ou par haine* où les deux derniers mots ne peuvent pas être enchainés sans un coup de glotte.

Answer (score 2):

[Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/h/38743/difficulte) dit :

> Le *h* initial peut être muet ou aspiré. Dans les deux cas, il ne représente **aucun son**. Si le *h* est muet, il y a élision ou liaison : *l'homme* ; *les hommes* (= lè-z-om). Si le *h* est aspiré, il n'y a ni élision ni liaison : *les héros* (= lè-éro).

Et [JPP](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/933/1514) semble confirmer que le standard (la règle, du moins) consiste à ne rien prononcer.

---

Pour situer `[lehal]`, les [tréfonds de Google](http://fr.lettres.langue.francaise.narkive.com/pFzrtUXn/h-aspire-moi-pas-connaitre)¹ me donnent :

> > Le *h* français n'est pas une consonne au sens phonétique et il est encore moins aspiré. En revanche, il existe bien un *h* consonne dans les parlers d'Alsace, de Lorraine et de Belgique, de Suisse. Comme en allemand, anglais, et néerlandais.
>
> [et](http://fr.lettres.langue.francaise.narkive.com/pFzrtUXn/h-aspire-moi-pas-connaitre.2)
>
> > Si, [le *h* aspiré existe comme consonne] en Normandie.
> >
> > La Hague, Saint Vaast la Hougue, etc. on prononce le *h* aspiré comme en
> >     anglais ou en allemand.
>
> Ainsi que :
>
> > Il me semble que le h, [en néerlandais](http://www.dutchgrammar.com/fr/?n=SpellingAndPronunciation.02), est non pas aspiré mais bien expiré. En le prononçant l'air sort de la bouche.

---

Reste à savoir d'où vient le coup de glotte, dont je confirme qu'il est assez courant.

¹ Attention, troll méchant.

Comment: Ta page trollesque donne la meilleure conclusion possible: « laissez-le aspirer du H, voyons ! ». Le coup de glotte contredit quand même ces braves gens : c'est une consonne, même s'il n'est pas aspiré, par contre ce n'est pas un phonème du français standard de 2012. Si on remplace *phonétique* par *phonologique*, ça marche.

Comment: Toujours à propos du coup de glotte, un autre exemple : *mille hiboux* ne peut pas enchainer le [mil] et le [ibu] sans insérer un coup de glotte (exemple emprunté à M-H Côté).

Answer (score 1):

Je me demande si la présence d'un *h* en tête ne se traduit pas par un son très légèrement plus long (ou sinon plus insistant) pour la seconde voyelle du mot, mais c'est une différence ténue, si tant est qu'elle existe.
Il ne faut pas oublier par contre le rôle du *h* pour autoriser ou non la liaison avec le mot suivant. C'est un indicateur très net quand on constate un défaut de prononciation de la liaison pour des personnes qui peuvent avoir une bonne culture du français littéral (écrit), mais non acquise à l'oral.