# Où est le « h aspiré » dans « anse » ?

Tags: prononciation, régionalismes, h-aspiré

J'ai une question sur le mot « anse ».

Comme tout le monde, je prononce ce mot `[ɑ̃s]` et comme tout le monde, ce mot commençant par une voyelle, j'applique les différents processus de [sandhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhi) en français : j'écris (et je prononce) « l'anse », je fais la liaison dans « une anse », « les anses », (soit à peu près `[yn‿ɑ̃s]`, `[le.zɑ̃s]` dans l'API ; de façon plus claire, je prononce « les anses » exactement comme « l'aisance ») etc.

« Comme tout le monde ? » C'est ce que je croyais quand j'étais jeune, naïf, et que je vivais à cent kilomètres de Paris. Depuis que je fréquente plus de gens du Sud, j'ai remarqué que certaines personnes, (dans mon corpus personnel, toutes originaires du Sud ou y ayant vécu), font comme si le mot *anse* était précédé d'un *h* aspiré : ils prononcent « la anse » (`[la.ʔɑ̃s]`) et ne font pas la liaison dans « une anse », « les anses », (`[yn.ʔɑ̃s]`, `[le.ʔɑ̃s]`) etc. Une rapide recherche Google montre d'ailleurs que l'orthographe « la anse », qui laisse peu de doutes sur la prononciation du scripteur, existe en proportion non négligeable.

Ma question est donc double :

1. Quelle est l'explication de cette prononciation ?
2. Quelle est la véritable étendue de cette prononciation ? (Est-ce vrai que cela ne concerne que le Sud de la France ? Quelle zone exactement ?)

Remarque : il existe bel et bien un mot « hanse » (comme dans « ville hanséatique », « Freie Hansestadt Bremen », etc.) avec un *h* aspiré. Mais ce mot étant plutôt rare (je crois bien ne jamais l'avoir entendu) et a priori pas vraiment sudiste, j'ai du mal à croire qu'il contienne la clef de l'énigme. Mais je peux me tromper…

Comment: Originaire de Toulouse je fais en effet cette distinction entre « les anses » et « l'aisance ». J'ai passé une dizaine d'années à Lyon et à Paris et je n'ai pourtant jamais remarqué que certains ne la faisaient pas.

Comment: A ma connaissance et pour mes pratiques de la langue de nos chauvins de voisins (suis suisse;), La liaison *doit* se faire. Cependant, je distingurai `l'aisance` de `les anses` en prononçant respectivement `lèzansse` et `lézansse` qui ressemblerait presque du coup à `l'escence`, ( de quoi donner de l'énergie au sujet ;)...

Comment: En tant que parisien, je confirme que je prononce l'aisance et les anses à l'identique

Comment: Noter qu'il y a d'autres mots français commençant par une voyelle pour lesquels il est standard de ne pas faire d'élision : "onze" ("le onze novembre"), "un" ("le deux, le un"), "une" ("la une d'un journal"), "oui" ("le oui l'emporte"), et "ouistiti" ("le ouistiti").

Comment: Hmm, à mon avis, c'est une liaison mal-t-à propos. Je pense que c'est régional. Ici en Suisse, on dit l'anse. Remarquez que ce sont les mêmes personnes qui disent « la anse » et qui ne font plus la différence entre le son « ain » et le son « un »…

Comment: @Oltarus: Les mêmes ? Tu ranges français du sud et français du nord dans le même panier ?

Answer (score 4):

Je pense qu'il s'agit d'une déformation régionale, car [l'élision](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89lision) devrait s'appliquer ici.

Pour la deuxième question je ne saurais dire, venant de l'île de la Réunion je n'ai jamais entendu "la anse", mais bien "l'anse" comme dans [l'anse des cascades](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anse_des_Cascades).

Answer (score 2):

Le fait de ne pas appliquer l'élision permet de lever une éventuelle ambiguïté.

> Les anses des seaux me blessent.
>
> L'aisance des sots me blesse.

Certes, l'exemple est un peu capilotracté.

Comment: Oui un besoin de désambiguïsation (hum, que ce mot est horrible) est une possibilité envisageable, mais je doute qu'elle soit vraiment nécessaire dans ce cas. Il y a beaucoup d'autres homonymes parmi les mots courants en français. Donc, sans arguments, indices ou preuves qui soutiendraient que c'est la véritable raison, j'ai peur de ne pas y croire du tout. Cela dit, c'est là un bel exemple :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Ailleurs](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/faire-un-pataques-en-faire-tout-un-pataques.php), on remarque la même chose :

> Un pataquès fréquent-z-en Belgique — peut-être aussi-t-ailleurs — concerne le mot *anse*. Que ce soit celle d'une tasse ou d'un panier, on dirait que le locuteur craint toute liaison avec ce mot. « Prends ta tasse par la anse », « tiens ton panier par les-h-anses ». Il n'y a pourtant pas de confusion possible avec « lance » ou « l'aisance ». Z'avez déjà entendu ça, vous ?

et plus bas :

> En Bretagne nord, chez moi donc, dans le Léon, y disent :
>   le auvent !

<sup>Et effectivement, d'autres disent que c'est méridional, mais je n'ai pas trouvé  le commencement d'une attestation pour ça.</sup>

Du coup, la distribution me fait un peu penser aux `[hal]` [qu'Evpok évoque](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/4396/1514), ce qui laisserait entendre que *là où on prononce le* h *en expirant, on rajoute naturellement des disjonctions quand il y a un [risque de confusion](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/French/other/315208-anse.html#823351)* (remarquez que qui dit « il est fréquent que […] l'élision ne soit pas faite dans le langage parlé » parle nativement **allemand** et français, pour ma distribution).

Ça donnerait Alsace, Lorraine, Belgique, Normandie, et Suisse, donc.

<sub>Je ne dis pas que mes références valent quelque chose, je dis qu'elles ne s'écrasent pas devant une opposition qui n'existe pas.</sub>

Comment: Je suis du sud ouest et c'est vrai que l'on dit "la anse" et "le auvent". C'est comme cela !